# R issue "object not found"

Tags: r

I am a newcomer to R. Last week I had a long and complicated function working perfectly. The program was letting me pick a subset of columns and doing various manipulations on that subset. The function must work 'function(arg1=first_header_name, arg2=second_header_name,....)'. I have cleared the console, removed the old history file. I have read the manual again, I have checked the .csv file to make sure everything there is still the same. I have gone back and reworked it all step by step and I have the place where this new problem occurs. As it is a very long function, I am only going to reproduce it in a simplified version of the part that is suddenly not working.

```
 elbow <- function(arg1,arg2) {
   my_data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",") 
   average_A <- (arg1 + arg2)
   average_A
 }
 elbow(A3,A5)
 # Error in elbow(A3, A5) : object 'A3' not found
```

Column headers are A3,A4,A5,A7,A8,A9,B2,B3,B5,B6,B7,B9

What stupid little error am I making? This is driving me batty. It has to be something trivial.

Comment: It thinks A3 and A5 are variables, try putting them in quotes, like 'A3' and 'A5'

Comment: Perhaps when it was working, you had done something like `attach(my_data)`? When `my_data` is not attached, you can't get directly at its columns, you have to go through `my_data` to get to them, e.g. `average_A <- my_data[, arg1] + my_data[, arg2]`.

Comment: That was it! I was missing the attach(my_data) #attach the variables in the dataframe to the workspace data. I had done it before and everything was still in the workspace when I got the whole thing running but when I quit that vanished. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my guess at what might work the way you wanted:

```
elbow <- function(arg1,arg2) {
   my_data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",") 
   average_A <- my_data[[arg1]] + my_data[[arg2]]   # "[[" evaluates args
   average_A
 }
 elbow('A3','A5')  # entered a character literals
```

You should realize that the rest of my_data will have evaporated and be garbage collected after return from the `elbow` call. I could have showed you how to use your original expression following `attach()`,  which would have been arguably safe within that function, but that would have violated my religious principles.

Comment: Ah, this is more elegant than mine. I'm so used to treating `data.frames` like matrices...

Comment: I think it would work with `my_data[ ,arg1]`.  Or I suppose: `my_data[ , grepl("arg1", names(my_data))]`

Comment: My way depends on the list structure of dataframes.

Comment: That ended up not being the slution but I appreciate the answer and I am looking at it in case it works better. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Probably during your last session you had objects named A3 or A5 in your workspace (either defined explicitly, or perhaps you had loaded and `attach`ed the data). The function was working because those objects were there, but it wasn't actually doing what you thought it was doing, so in a new session with a new workspace--without those objects--it's not working. Your function as written doesn't actually do anything with the dataset (`my_data`) which you are reading in inside of it; I suspect you want something like this:

```
elbow <- function(arg1, arg2) {
  my_data <- read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
  average_A <- my_data[,arg1] + my_data[,arg2]
  return(average_A) 
}
```

You will also need to use quotes when calling the function, e.g.

```
elbow('A3','A5')
```

Comment: Good explanation, but I think this line: `average_A <- my_data[,which(arg1==names(read.csv))] + my_data[,which(arg2==names(read.csv))]` is a bit off?

Comment: @Marius Of course, that should be `my_data`, not `read.csv`. Thanks!