# Predicting problems in r: object not found in a glm model

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to predict the "Profundidad" variable from the following model:

```
Mfsin <- glm(Riqueza~Anof+Profundidad+Fondof, family=poisson, data=lancessin)
```

but I am having some problems during my data.frame construction:

```
dat <- data.frame(y=rnorm(50),Profundidad=sample(10:15,50,replace=TRUE))
Mfsin2 <- glm(y~Anof+Profundidad+Fondof,data=dat)
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Anof' not found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R issue "object not found"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469486/r-issue-object-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

The data frame on which you're computing the model, 'dat', was generated with only two variables: y and Profundidad. There is therefore no variables Anof or Fondof in the data frame.

You need to use cbind to add the Anof and Fondof columns from the lancessin data frame to the 'dat' data frame.

Comment: `dat <- cbind(dat, lancessin[,c('Anof', 'Fondof')])` Note that `dat` and `lancessin` must have the same number of rows. If not, `cbind` will actually cycle back through the data frame with less rows to populate additional rows, similar to the idea of how R adds two vectors with different lengths.

Comment: Many thanks Dylan,> dat <- data.frame(y=rnorm(299), Profundidad=sample(0:180,299,replace=TRUE))
> dat <- cbind(dat, lancessin[,c('Anof', 'Fondof')])
> Mfsin2 <- glm(y~Anof+Profundidad+Fondof,data=dat)
> nuevaprof<-seq(0, 180, 0.01)
> predict.prof <- predict(Mfsin2, dat=data.frame(Profundidad=nuevaprof), interval="confidence", level=0.90, type="response")
> yprof <- predict.prof
> lines(nuevaprof, yprof)
Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Comment: It really works now. please take a look to the scripts above, I don´t know why X and Y differs.